# Options Pattern Class not Populating

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-6.0, worker

I'm creating a .NET 6 worker service, hosted as a windows service. The service uses the FluentFTP library to download files from a remote server. I'm trying to implement strongly-typed configuration using the Options Pattern but am having difficulties with the binding.

```
public class Program
{      
    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var config = new ConfigurationBuilder().Build();
        var logger = LogManager.Setup()
            .SetupExtensions(ext => ext.RegisterConfigSettings(config))
            .GetCurrentClassLogger();
        
        IHost host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseWindowsService(Options => { Options.ServiceName = "Foo FTP File Process"; })
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
            {
                config.Sources.Clear();
                IHostEnvironment env = hostingContext.HostingEnvironment;
        
                config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                    .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", true, true);
                IConfigurationRoot configurationRoot = config.Build();
        
                FTPSettingsOptions options = new();
                configurationRoot.GetSection(nameof(FTPSettingsOptions))
                    .Bind(options);

                //Working
                Console.WriteLine($"FTPSettingsOptions.Enabled={options.FTPUsername}");
            })
            .ConfigureServices(services =>
            {
                services.AddOptions();                   
                services.AddSingleton<IFTPService, FTPService>();
                services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
            })
            .ConfigureLogging((hostContext, logging) =>
            {
                logging.ClearProviders();
                logging.AddNLog(hostContext.Configuration, new NLogProviderOptions() 
                { LoggingConfigurationSectionName = "NLog" });
                logging.AddConsole();
                logging.SetMinimumLevel(Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LogLevel.Trace);
            })
            .Build();
                    
        await host.RunAsync();
    }
}
```

appSettings.Development.json:

```
{
  "FTPSettingsOptions": {
    "FTPUri": "ftp://ftp.foo.com",
    "FTPUsername": "footest",
    "FTPPassword": "***********",
    "FTPServerPath": "/home/footest/foo",
    "CallServerPath": "C:\\Temp\\foo"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  }
}
```

POCO Class:

```
public class FTPSettingsOptions
{
    public FTPSettingsOptions() { }

    public const string FTPSettings = "FTPSettings";

    public string FTPUri { get; set; } = String.Empty;
    public string FTPUsername { get; set; } = String.Empty;
    public string FTPPassword { get; set; } = String.Empty;
    public string FTPServerPath { get; set; } = String.Empty;
    public string CallServerPath { get; set; } = String.Empty;
}
```

**This is where the options values are coming in as null:**

```
public class FTPService : IFTPService
{
    private readonly IOptions<FTPSettingsOptions> _options;
    
    public FTPService(IOptions<FTPSettingsOptions> options)
    {
        FTPSettingsOptions _options = options.Value;
        
        // Connect only once (Singleton scope)
        Connect();
    }

    public void Connect()
    {
        // FTPUsername and FTPPassword have no values
        using ( var conn = new FtpClient(_options.Value.FTPUri, _options.Value.FTPUsername,                           
            _options.Value.FTPPassword))
        {
            ...
            conn.Connect();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the `Configure` call:

```
.ConfigureServices((ctx, services) =>
{
    services.Configure<FTPSettingsOptions>(ctx.Configuration.GetSection(nameof(FTPSettingsOptions)));
    // ...
})
```

Note that explicit `AddOptions` call is not needed because `Configure` performs it internally.

`configurationRoot.GetSection(nameof(FTPSettingsOptions)).Bind(options);` just binds the data to `options` instance and does not register anything in the DI (check the docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-7.0) or [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/options)).

Comment: the FTPService constructor now has values populated in options.Value, but it is still blowing up with null reference in the Connect() using statement... FTPUsername and FTPPassword are still blank.

Comment: @IrishChieftain I would assume that `FTPSettingsOptions _options = options.Value;` hides the `_options` field so it is not initialized. Change this line to `_options = options`.

Comment: @IrishChieftain also I would argue that connecting to ftp in class constructor is kind of a code smell and should be avoided.